# UIImage performance: imageNamed vs UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext from bezierPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

In our app, instead of using an asset library to store all of our app's images (for all display types -  2x, 3x), we are drawing each image using `UIBezierPath` to the context `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`.

Is this an efficient and robust way of using images within our app? Or is it more efficient to use pre-rendered assets?

My hunch is that its slowing things down - For example, inside `UITableView` it needs to draw the image and get it from the context for every `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, instead of grabbing it from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will certainly reduce the app size for download but you don't want to be regenerating the images repeatedly at runtime. This will certainly slow the app down. Instead consider starting a process when the app is launched which creates all of the images and caches them to disk. Consider also creating your own in-memory cache so that you don't need to keep loading frequently used images from disk.